# How to declare inline static members in classes?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, class, static, inline

When you wanna use a static variable in a class, you have to define it first with the inline command, if you wanna do it in the class declaration, right?

```
static inline int p_iMaxID = 0;
```

But why does my VS 2019 does not allow me to use the inline command?
It says:

'A non static datamember cannot be declared as inline'

Comment: What *language* in VS? And where does this “inline” keyword come from?

Comment: It is c++, the inline keyword is from my university script. An if i leave it out, vs tell me to use it

Comment: You probably don't have c++17 enabled. VS 2019 defaults to c++14.

Comment: Where can i enable c++17

Comment: Under project properties. I'd seriously recommend familiarizing yourself with your compiler and its settings.

Comment: Yes i already found now it is working, thank you. Yea that is what am trying to do, i just switched to vs code 2 days ago.